# Draw a line from .Point depending on attribute & without re-sizing with zoom

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I am adding points to the map and then giving them a speed attribute

I want to be able to have a line that represents the speed from position 0 of the point e.g. 200 knots = 200 pixels (then some math to keep it at a reasonable length).

I also need it not to be longer/shorter depending on the zoom

What i have so far:

```
  var vlPoint = OpenLayers.Point;     
  var vlPixel = OpenLayers.Pixel; 
  var vlSpeed = itemData.mIntendedMovement.mSpeedOverGround;       
  vlPixel.add(point, vlSpeed);
  vlPoint.move(0, vlPixel);
```

I am very new to OpenLayers and cannot find anything on the OpenLayers dev pages or on SO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, all it needed was:

```
var vlPoint = OpenLayers.Point;  
var length = (itemData.mIntendedMovement.mSpeedOverGround * this.map.resolution)/10;
vlPoint.move(0, length);
```

Sometimes its the simple things